# Implementing plugin with HTML/CSS form?

Tags: plugin-development

I am working on my first WordPress plugin. On the browser side some html/css/jQuery code implements a simple popup dialog form. The user enters a text field, clicks on a button and an ajax call takes the input and does some db processing. All is working fine.

Currently the plugin contains some settings and server side code. Now I am thinking of adding the user input form to the plugin for the browser side.

Should a plugin contain an HTML input form and CSS that will commonly be alien (especially the CSS) to the look and feel of any theme that would download it? If it can be done, what is the recommended way of implementing it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you try to explain it again?

Comment: Edited - hope that helps.

Comment: For admin side, there is a set of classes you can use to make your forms looks like the rest of the admin desing. In the frontend there is not such solution as each theme uses its own CSS identifiers that you can not know. You can try to inherit CSS rules when possible but that don't ensure a result that exactly match the look and feel of theme.